# How to get the full test coverage of the tested method

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5

I'm writing unit tests for a Spring Boot Service, and I want to get the full coverage of the GET method. Here's my GET method:

```
public void updateCar(String id, String carModel, Integer HP, Integer year, String designer) {
    Garage garage = garageRepository.findById(id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException(
                    "A car with the id " + id + " is not in our Garage."));
    if(carModel != null && carModel.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(garage.getCarModel(), carModel)) {
        garage.setCarModel(carModel);
    }
    if(HP != null && !Objects.equals(garage.getHP(), HP)) {
        garage.setHP(HP);
    }
    if(year != null && !Objects.equals(garage.getYear(), year)) {
        garage.setYear(year);
    }
    if(designer != null && designer.length() > 0 && !Objects.equals(garage.getDesigner(), designer)) {
        garage.setDesigner(designer);
    }
    garageRepository.save(garage);
}
}
```

And here is the test method I wrote:

```
 @Test
    @DisplayName("Update Car Test")
    void testUpdateCar() {

    Garage updatedGarage = new Garage();
    String id = "630ca281f12905d5f5249f08";
    String carModel = "Updated carModel";
    int HP = 480;
    int year = 1964;
    String designer = "Updated designer";

    updatedGarage.setId(id);
    updatedGarage.setCarModel(carModel);
    updatedGarage.setHP(HP);
    updatedGarage.setYear(year);
    updatedGarage.setDesigner(designer);

    when(garageRepository.findById(id))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(updatedGarage));
    garageService.updateCar(id, carModel, HP, year, designer);

    when(garageRepository.save(updatedGarage))
            .thenReturn(updatedGarage);
    verify(garageRepository).findById(id);
    }
```

With the test, I only get partial coverage. To be precise, the test didn't include `garage.setCarModel(carModel)`, `garage.setHP(HP)`, `garage.setYear(year)` nor the `garage.setDesigner(designer)` from the `updateCar` method. Can anyone give me a clue or point me in the right direction, on how to get the full coverage?

Comment: Your `if` includes `&& !Objects.equals(garage.getCarModel(), carModel)`, but the values are equal. So why do you expect `garage.setCarModel(carModel);` to be called? Think about what your code does: update a `Garage` (shouldn't that class be calle `Car`?) and overwrite existing field values (model, hp, ..) with new values if they differ. Your test case does not create a scenario for the "if they differ" part.

Comment: I just removed that part of the code, and the coverage went to 100%. I was completely blind to equal values in `if`.
I wasn't aware of the missing part in my test case (I'm fairly new to testing). Can you show me an example of what the case should look like?

Comment: Well that code is there for a reason, you shouldn't remove actual code just to get your coverage up. You need to create a testing scenario around the existing code. All you need to do is make your `updatedGarage` object have different values than the ones you pass to the `garageService.updateCar` method call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, understand the paths in the method and then write tests for each path.

There are three main paths and subpaths in the code. To get the full coverage test needs these conditions.

1. `garageRepository.findById(id) ...`

- findById returns a value
- findById throws Exception

2. `carModel != null && carModel.length() > 0 ...`

- carModel is  NOT null.
- carModel length is NOT 0
- garage carModel is NOT the same as carModel passed.

3. `if(HP != null && !Objects.equals(garage.getHP(), HP)) ...`

- HP is NOT null
- HP is NOT the same as HP passed

4. `if(designer != null && designer.length() > 0 ...`

- designer is  NOT null.
- designer length is NOT 0
- garage designer is NOT same as designer passed.

5. `garageRepository.save(garage) ...

- Executes when `findById` is success.

In the code.

1. `updatedGarage` values and values passed to `garageService.updateCar` must change.

```
when(garageRepository.findById(id))
            .thenReturn(Optional.of(updatedGarage));
    garageService.updateCar(id, carModel, HP, year, designer);
```

2. Add a test for findById to throw an exception.

```
when(garageRepository.findById(id))
            .thenThrow(NullPointerException.class);
```